# setting parameters in upstream job

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson

I have a multijob structure of the form:

JobA
   JobB
   JobC

I want that part of its run JobB will set parameters in JobA so after JobB finishes JobA will be able to pass it to JobC.

I've tried to look at the multijob plugin itself but didn't find any way to do it.
Also tried googling various searches on the subject with or without groovy but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Is it JobB that triggers JobC, or does JobA trigger JobC once JobB has completed?

Comment: Is it possible to change the job structure so JobB triggers JobC?

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem by using a groovy script:

```
def my_run = Thread.currentThread().executable
def my_parent_run = my_run.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause).getUpstreamRun()

def preExistingAction = my_parent_run .getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction.class)
my_parent_run.getActions().remove(preExistingAction)
def params = preExistingAction ?. iterator() ?. toList() ?: []
params << new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('TEST_PARAM', 'FOO')
my_parent_run.addAction(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(params))
```

It's important that the script will be a "system" using script ("Execute System Groovy Scripts" build step) so that the script with run in the context on the Jenkins JVM and will be able to import the Build object.

So JobB runs this script, and then when it finishes this build step, JobA now has a parameter called "TEST_PARAM" with value "FOO", which it can easily pass to JobC in any of the standard ways.

Note that I'm using fully qualified names, but you can `import hudson.model.*` and get rid of the all `hudson.modle.` in the script.

I aim to write and publish a plugin that will do just that, as I think it's a useful feature in many cases.

Comment: I needed to add a param to the current build for a BuildFlow job (which is why environment variable via EnvInject wouldn't work). EnvInject plugin gave me "currentBuild" on which I could call "getAction", "getActions" and "addAction" methods (based on your script). Thank you for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way of doing it with your current job structure, however if you change the jobs so that `JobB` triggers `JobC`, then you can achieve what you want using the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). Using this you would configure your jobs as follows:

**JobA**

In *Post-Build Actions*, setup to *Trigger Parameterized Build* of `JobB`. Under *Add Parameters* select *Predefined Parameters* and enter the parameters you want to pass on.

**JobB**

In *Post-Build Actions*, setup to *Trigger Parameterized Build* of `JobC`. Then there are a number of ways you may want to pass parameters (note that you can combine these different approaches to passing parameters).

- To pass on the parameters already defined by `JobA`, under *Add Parameters* select *Current Build Parameters*.
- To have `JobB` programatically determine parameters to pass to `JobC`, have `JobB` output them to a properties file, and then pass these to `JobC` by selecting *Parameters from properties file* under *Add parameters*, and enter the file you stored them in.
- To manually enter further parameters in the job configuration, under *Add Parameters* select *Predefined Parameters* and enter the parameters you want to pass on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good, but will not work in my use case. In our enterprise we have a very complex build tree with lots of multijobs  hierarchies and I don't have the freedom to change the structure.